# Django excluding a queryset without values() keyword

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a few models but my question is about two of them, A and B.

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    c = models.CharField(...)
    d = models.ForeignKey(C)
```

All i want is to exclude this queryset:

```
set1 = B.objects.all()
```

From below queryset:

```
set2 = A.objects.all()
```

I know i can manage this by:

```
set1 = B.objects.all().values('a')
set2 = A.objects.all().exclude(pk__in = set1)
```

But i need all values of set1 for the remaining code. If i use values(), i cant use "c" and "d" fields of set1.

So, is there any method excluding without narrowing the fields of B?

PS: i prefer to keep away from new queries. i know i can write a second query of B objects to fit my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are asking for the instances of model A with no related B.

```
set2 = A.objects.filter(b__isnull=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a list comprehension:

```
[obj.a for obj in queryset]
```

This will return a list with the `a` attribute for all the objects in the queryset, without modifying them.

Comment: i think it'll make new queries to gather obj.a for queryset, am i wrong?

Comment: A queryset is lazy, it will be evaluated when you iterate over it. If `a` is a foreign key or a related field, then you'll do a query to feach the related object for every iteration. If that is the case, then you should use `select_related()` or `fetch_related()` depending on the case, if performance is an issue for you. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related